# Specifying order of operations in ModelBuilder using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have a tool that exports attachments from an existing feature class and another one that takes those photos from a given folder and turns them into points on the map. I am trying to use ModelBuilder to combine these two into one process, go from photo attachments in one feature class to a point feature class layer. I am running into an issue though.

Whenever I run the model, the geotag photo to points tool will run first before the attachment remover can, thus creating an empty point feature class. I have tried to look into preconditions but the attachment remover doesn't generate anything like a feature class that I could use to set as a precondition. I will have the model pasted below.

Does anyone have any idea how to set the attachment remover tool to go first or how to mess with the sequence that tools are run within the model?

[image]

Comment: The export attachment tool in your picture is a custom tool? If you right click it, do you have anything from *create variable* > *from parameter*? Hopefully you do, so you can add that, assuming its an output, to make into a pre-condition for GeoTagged Photos tool

Comment: Why is Attachments connected to the GeoTagged tool and Attachments? This looks a bit circular. I also agree with Khibma.

Comment: The export attachment tool doesn't have any output that can be used as a precondition which is the issue. Also I have in that picture the attachments set up as a precondition but that doesn't work to stop the Geotagged Photos to Points from going first. I have even trying going into my custom export attachment tool to add another output but it wouldn't work.

Comment: can you post the "ExportAttachements" model? (Use the 'Edit' link to update your question).

Comment: Export your model to a Python script and edit that output in a Python IDE to ensure Export attachments code executes before geotagging.

Comment: I agree with @KHibma, the modelbuilder way of setting order is to set the output of the tool to be a precondition of the geotag to point tool. There is no Export Attachment tool in ArcPro toolbox so it must be a custom model/python script. Who ever set it up did a poor job by not exposing an output which could be used as a precondition. I would go back to the person who created the tool and get them to adjust it. You were definitely on the right path on using preconditions to control order of operations.

Comment: I think it's clear the Export Attachment tool needs some work. If that isn't an option, your only other possible option might be to create a new model and drag tools into it, IN ORDER that you want them to RUN. There is no guarantee MB will honor that, but in your case of 2 tools, it's literally a 2minute test.